# JavaFX - White overlay for UI elements in CSS

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm tryin to follow the [material design guide](https://material.io/design/color/dark-theme.html#properties) for my application's color scheme. At the moment, I'm at the part where it's explaining how the dark theme works.

This is my `CSS`:

```
#main-app {
    -fx-background-color: #121212;
    -fx-background-radius: 5px;
}

#top-bar {
    -fx-background-color: bar-color;
    -fx-background-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
#bottom-bar {
    -fx-background-color: bar-color;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
```

How can I do the 5% overlay, as seen in the image below, of my `#main-app`'s `background-color` so I can then apply it to the top and bottom bars?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give it another shot ;-)

CSS File:

```
#main-app {
    -fx-background-radius: 5px;
    -fx-background-color: #121212;
}

#top-bar {
    -fx-background-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    -fx-background-color: inherit;
}

#top-bar-overlay {
    -fx-background-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    -fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}

#bottom-bar {
    -fx-background-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -fx-background-color: inherit;
}

#bottom-bar-overlay {
    -fx-background-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

FXML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Spinner?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane stylesheets="@styling2.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.OverlayController">
   <children>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <Label text="Transparency Value for Top Bar Overlay:" />
            <Spinner fx:id="topBarTransparencySpinner" />
            <Label text="Transparency Value for Bottom Bar Overlay:" />
            <Spinner fx:id="bottomBarTransparencySpinner" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <GridPane id="main-app" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="27.0">
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
         </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <AnchorPane id="top-bar">
               <children>
                  <HBox id="top-bar" alignment="CENTER" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label text="Top Bar">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="36.0" />
                           </font>
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets />
                           </HBox.margin>
                        </Label>
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
                  <Pane id="top-bar-overlay" fx:id="topBarOverlayPane" mouseTransparent="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <children>
                  <HBox id="bottom-bar" alignment="CENTER" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label text="Bottom Bar">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="36.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
                  <Pane id="bottom-bar-overlay" fx:id="bottomBarOverlayPane" mouseTransparent="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller Class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class OverlayController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    Spinner<Double>
            topBarTransparencySpinner,
            bottomBarTransparencySpinner;
    @FXML
    private Pane
            topBarOverlayPane,
            bottomBarOverlayPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        topBarTransparencySpinner.setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory(0, 1, 0.05, 0.01));
        bottomBarTransparencySpinner.setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory(0, 1, 0.5, 0.01));

        topBarTransparencySpinner.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldV, newV) ->
                topBarOverlayPane.setStyle(String.format("-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, %s);", String.valueOf(newV).replace(",", "."))));
        bottomBarTransparencySpinner.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldV, newV) ->
                bottomBarOverlayPane.setStyle(String.format("-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, %s);", String.valueOf(newV).replace(",", "."))));
    }
}
```

Preview:

[image: Preview]

Does this example help you for your project?

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant, mate. I appreciate the hard work. It helped me understand overlays much better! I also took another look at the colors after taking a break from programming and it turned out my eyes were just tired and the colors are the same, which means Cas' answer is also correct. Unfortunately, I can only mark one as correct and since this is more complete I've decided to mark it as the answer. Again, I'm extremely thankful!

Answer (score 1):

If you main background is already black, I think you can use an rgba background-color on the blocks. So for a 5% white overlay rgba(255,255,255,0.05).

I'm not sure if this is what you looking for but I hope it can help you a bit.

Comment: I just tried this + the equivalent in `HEX` - `#FFFFFF0D` - and if I'm not mistaken, there seems to be just a slight difference between the color I get and the one from the image with the 5% overlay. Mine seems to be a bit darker.

Comment: Yes. "anko" has provided me with a good solution. Yours is not incorrect, but his answer is more complete and has given me more insight on how overlays work. I appreciate your help as well though!

Comment: Thank you, I agree with you :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not possible with css only. Here is one example for a possible solution:

Controller Class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private FlowPane rootFlowPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        for (int i = 0; i < rootFlowPane.getChildren().size(); i++) {
            Node node = rootFlowPane.getChildren().get(i);
            if (node instanceof Pane) {
                Pane pane = (Pane) node;

                String style = "-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, %s); -fx-background-radius: 5; -fx-border-color: grey;";

                if (i == 0)
                    pane.setStyle(String.format(style, "0"));
                else if (i == 1)
                    pane.setStyle(String.format(style, "0.05"));
                else if (i == 2)
                    pane.setStyle(String.format(style, "0.07"));
                else if (i >= 100)
                    pane.setStyle(String.format(style, "1"));
                else {
                    String transparency = String.format("%.2f", (i + 5) / 100.0).replace(",", ".");
                    pane.setStyle(String.format(style, transparency));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FXML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>


<FlowPane fx:id="rootFlowPane" hgap="20.0" prefHeight="460.0" prefWidth="460.0" style="-fx-background-color: #121212;" vgap="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
   </padding>
</FlowPane>
```

Preview:

[image: Preview]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think you might've misunderstood something though. I won't be doing a list with rectangles that have different overlay percentages. The image I've posted is a screenshot of the part of the guide I'm currently looking into, so people won't have to bother opening the link and searching for it. I'll only be using a single overlay percentage for both bars, which can be done in `CSS` as "Cas Heynen" has suggested, `setStyle` does the same, just in a programatic way. I appreciate the work you've put into it though. 1/2

Comment: If I were to use multiple colors, it would be the wright answer. Doing it programatically unfortunately, seems to produce the same color as doing it through `CSS`. <s>Check my original post for the edit in 2min</s> Updated. I think there's a slight difference in color, but then again, I might be imagining / my eyes might not be right. 2/2

Comment: Udated my original post.

Comment: You are welcome and excuse me that I misunderstood your question. Maybe someone else can help.